# $|a_kz_1^k|\leq1$ for all but finitely many $k$ if power series convergent in $z_1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading in a book on complex analysis that if a power series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k$ converges for $z_1\in\mathbb{C}$ then it converges also for all $z\in \mathbb{C},\,\, |z|< |z_1|.$ Then, it states the following without explanation:$$ |a_kz^k|=|a_kz_1^k|\,|\frac{z^k}{z_1^k}| \leq | \frac{z}{z_1}|^k, \,\,$$ whereby $|a_kz_1^k|\leq1$ for all but finitely many $k.$ My question is: why does the part of the statement "$|a_kz_1^k|\leq1$ for all but finitely many $k$" hold ? For those finetely many $k$ then the right hand side will not be bounded by $1$ and thus one can not build the geometric series needed to provide the further statement according to which the given series will be bounded by the geometric series.

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^zz_1^{\,k}$ converges, you have $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_kz_1^{\,k}=0$. Therefore, $\left|a_kz_1^{\,k}\right|\leqslant1$ if $k$ is large enough. In other words, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $k\geqslant N\implies\left|a_kz_1^{\,k}\right|\leqslant1$. Since the series $\sum_{k=N}^\infty\left|\frac z{z_1}\right|^k$ converges, then so does the series $\sum_{k=N}^\infty\left|a_kz_1^{\,k}\right|\left|\frac z{z_1}\right|^k$. But this implies that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left|a_kz_1^{\,k}\right|\left|\frac z{z_1}\right|^k$ converges too.